# Postgres convert time without minutes in format

Tags: postgresql, timestamp

I expected this to be easier than it is, but I have a table with times in it in a format like:

```
11:35:00 
12:02:00 
13:04:00
```

I need to return those times so it only shows:

```
11:35
12:02
13:04
```

Every solution I can find online says to use

`date_trunc('minute', time_here)`

That just returns the time in the same seconds format that it is already in. I want the seconds completely removed from the format. Any way to just change it to HH:MM format? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is for display purposes, with for example the following definition:

```
create table t1 (tt timestamp);
insert into t1 values ('2018-08-24 12:10:00');
insert into t1 values ('2018-08-24 11:02:00');
insert into t1 values ('2018-08-24 13:00:30');
```

The the following:

```
select to_char(tt, 'HH24:MI') from t1;
```

will produce:

```
to_char
12:20
11:02
13:00
```

date_trunc leaves the data as a timestamp and a select on a timestamp will display in the usual format.  Explicit conversion to char (as with to_char) allows different layouts.
Documentation on all different formatting options for this can be found [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.2/static/functions-formatting.html)

Comment: Thanks! For my purpose I only needed to do the "select to_char(tt, 'HH24:MI')" part of the answer, but that works.